# Pass parameters to a task raises convert type error

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have 2 async methods to download files from Dropbox:

1. static: downloading static file from static folder
2. dynamic: downloads the file and folder based on parameters

The dynamic approach fails and I want to understand why (i have a work around in mind using object properties ).

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task = Task.Run((Func<Task>)Business.DownloadFileFromDropBox);
    task.Wait();

    /* this fails: CS0030 Cannot convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 
       'System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' */
    var task2 = Task.Run((Func<Task>)Business.DownloadFromDB("/Files", "File.txt"));
    task2.Wait();
}
```

I suspect there is a problem with my approach to tasks and parameters.

The called methods are as follows:

```
    public static async Task DownloadFileFromDropBox()
    {
        string _pathname = "/Files";
        string _filename = "xHistoriekFondsen.csv";
        using (var dbx = new DropboxClient(DropBoxToken))
        {
           using (var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync(_pathname +"/" +  _filename))
            {
                var s = response.GetContentAsByteArrayAsync();
                s.Wait();
                var d = s.Result;
                File.WriteAllBytes(_filename, d);
            }
        }

    }
```

And the other one:

```
public static async Task DownloadFromDB(string _pathname, string _filename )
    {
        using (var dbx = new DropboxClient(DropBoxToken))
        {
            using (var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync(_pathname + "/" + _filename))
            {
                var s = response.GetContentAsByteArrayAsync();
                s.Wait();
                var d = s.Result;
                File.WriteAllBytes(_filename, d);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `Task.Run(()=>DownloadFromDB("/Files", "File.txt"));`, maybe (can't test).  `(Func<Task>)` is not that useful in the first snippet.

Comment: Any specific reason why do you need a type cast (Func<Task>) ?

Comment: No specifiek reason for the type cast, the answer below actually explains it it not necessary.

Comment: There also the strange thing that you're using `.Wait()` in an `async` method. Can't you `await response.GetContentAsByteArrayAsync();`?

Comment: In that approach, how do i catch the result into s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calls which you did in `btnDownload_Click` are fundamentally different which leads you to a reasonable compile-time error.

1. Pass method delegate to `Task.Run`

In the first case (`Task.Run((Func<Task>)Business.DownloadFileFromDropBox)`), you've passed `DownloadFileFromDropBox` method [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) to the `Task.Run` method which works as expected since `Task.Run` has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Func_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__) which takes `Func<Task>` as parameter.

Since the type of the method delegate is `Func<Task>`, which is built-
in generic [delegate type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=netframework-4.7.2), casting is not needed, you can just pass it into the method:
`Task.Run(Business.DownloadFileFromDropBox)`

2. Invoke async method and pass the result to `Task.Run`

In the second case (`Task.Run((Func<Task>)Business.DownloadFromDB("/Files", "File.txt"))`), you are actually invoking `DownloadFromDB` method and passing result (type of `Task`) of it into the `Task.Run` method. That expectedly causes a compile-time error due to casting incompatibility between `Task` and `Func<Task>` types.

To conclude, you don't need to wrap `Task` into another `Task` via `Task.Run` method, you can just directly invoke `Wait` on `Task` object returned from both download methods.

```
var downloadFromDropBoxTask = Business.DownloadFileFromDropBox();
downloadFromDropBoxTask.Wait();

var downloadFromDBTask = Business.DownloadFromDB("/Files", "File.txt");
downloadFromDBTask.Wait()
```

If you won't perform any operations (e.g. error handling) on your task variable, you can inline `Wait` call:

```
Business.DownloadFileFromDropBox().Wait();
Business.DownloadFromDB("/Files", "File.txt").Wait();
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand the  basic issue on passing a delegate or passing a result.  
When following the suggestion invoke without the Task.Run the Wait statements seems  to wait forever.  

        `/*works fine*/
        var downloadFromDropBoxTask = Task.Run( Business.DownloadFileFromDropBox );
        downloadFromDropBoxTask.Wait();`

`       `/*seems to wait forever*/
        var InvokeWithWait = Business.DownloadFileFromDropBox();
        InvokeWithWait.Wait(); `

Comment: @MaartenDaniels it seems to me you ended up with a deadlock, which may happen when mixing sync and async code. Could you fix your download methods, and use `await` instead of `Wait` since methods are marked as `async`. So, the following should be used: `var d = await response.GetContentAsByteArrayAsync()`. In addition to that, you can mark your `btnDownload_Click` method as `async void`, and just asynchronously wait download methods. For example, `await Business.DownloadFileFromDropBox().ConfigureAwait(false);`. `ConfigureAwait` is important to avoid deadlock on main thread.